# Selenium Webdriver Android

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run android tests on my PC. Everything is setup as [per the instructions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver).
Instead of launching the test in the android emulator, an instance of IE is launched instead. I can see the robot icon for android in my grid console page look as it is being executed.

I am expecting the test to be launched in the emulator, not IE - am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

In actual, the Layout you have used here might be a latest one.

Whenever you run the test, separate apk will be downloaded in your emulator. Probably, it is not the IE; if so please give details about the IE version.

Comment: It is IE that is launched, version 10. I cant see that the latest APK is downloaded.